# Microsoft Small Business Licensing Kick Start

Tags: sql-server, licensing, active-directory

I seem to recall hearing at some point (I believe it was MIX09) that Microsoft has a licensing model of some sort where a business can consume licenses for up to two years, free of charge, until they reach a point where they are stable position and can pay their licensing at the end of two years.  However, I can't find information regarding it online.

I want to say that possibly stackoverflow used this licensing model to kick start their site.  Is anyone familiar with this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to BizSpark (as per @paul) there are also WebSpark and, as of May 2010, the developer MAPS programmes.

Webspark information is here: http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark/default.aspx

Details of the Action Pack (MAPS) are currently here: https://partner.microsoft.com/global/40132997

I'm fairly certain that in all cases availablility varies by your location - but if you're producing stuff for/with/on Microsoft tools/platforms then they're all worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking of BizSpark:

http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/

There is also the Empower program if you're an existing business, not a startup.